# I want to go to the next question when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript

I want to go to the next question when the button is pressed

Each time a button is clicked, the new question and the answers to the question should come into the container.

```
const Questions = [
  {
    question: "Which planet has the largest size in our Solar System?",
    options: ["Mars", "Venus", "Jupiter", "Neptune"],
    correctAnswer: "Jupiter",
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which element is represented by the symbol 'Fe' in the periodic table?",
    options: ["Iron", "Phosphorus", "Copper", "Silver"],
    correctAnswer: "Iron",
  },
  {
    question: "Which famous painter created the artwork 'Mona Lisa'?",
    options: [
      "Vincent van Gogh",
      "Pablo Picasso",
      "Leonardo da Vinci",
      "Michelangelo",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Leonardo da Vinci",
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which planet is sometimes referred to as the 'Morning Star' of the universe?",
    options: ["Mars", "Venus", "Jupiter", "Uranus"],
    correctAnswer: "Venus",
  },
  {
    question:
      "Which prominent English writer authored works like 'Romeo and Juliet' and 'Hamlet'?",
    options: [
      "Charles Dickens",
      "Jane Austen",
      "William Shakespeare",
      "Mark Twain",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "William Shakespeare",
  },
  {
    question: "Which planet is also known as the 'Red Planet'?",
    options: ["Mars", "Venus", "Jupiter", "Neptune"],
    correctAnswer: "Mars",
  },
  {
    question: "On which date was the Republic of Turkey officially declared?",
    options: [
      "October 29, 1923",
      "July 15, 2016",
      "May 19, 1919",
      "April 23, 1920",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "October 29, 1923",
  },
  {
    question: "Which element is a major component of Earth's atmosphere?",
    options: ["Oxygen", "Hydrogen", "Nitrogen", "Carbon dioxide"],
    correctAnswer: "Nitrogen",
  },
  {
    question: "What is the largest mammal on Earth?",
    options: ["Elephant", "Blue whale", "Giraffe", "Lion"],
    correctAnswer: "Blue whale",
  },
  {
    question: "Which renowned scientist formulated the equation 'E=mc²'?",
    options: [
      "Isaac Newton",
      "Galileo Galilei",
      "Albert Einstein",
      "Nikola Tesla",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Albert Einstein",
  },
];

let currentQuestionIndex = 0;
let score = 0;

const deneme = document.querySelector(".container");

displayQuestion();

function displayQuestion() {
  const currentQuestion = Questions[currentQuestionIndex];
  const question = document.querySelector(".title");
  const answerContainer = document.querySelector(".options");

  question.innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;

  // Answers
  currentQuestion.options.forEach((option) => {
    const answer = document.createElement("div");
    answer.innerText = option;
    answer.classList.add("answer");
    answerContainer.appendChild(answer);

    answer.addEventListener("click", function () {
      checkAnswer(option);
    });
  });
}

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++;
});

function checkAnswer(selectedOption) {
  const currentQuestion = Questions[currentQuestionIndex];
  const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next");

  if (selectedOption === currentQuestion.correctAnswer) {
    score++;
  }

  nextBtn.classList.add("open");
}
```

I want to go to the next question when the button is pressed

What I've already tried: :

`nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { currentQuestionIndex++; });`

I've been trying something for almost half an hour but I still couldn't find the solution please help

Comment: When asking questions, try to give a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also make sure to state what errors you are seeing with your current implementation/code. It makes it easier for people to help you and for your question to be useful to other who could also have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Do you call the `displayQuestion` function after incrementing `currentQuestionIndex`? If not, you should do that.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted, it looks like you're calling the click event on `nextBtn` outside of the function which you declare it. That would make the call outside of the scope of it's originally declared variable. Try declaring it at the top of your file.

Additionally, you should make sure you have a conditional for when they get to the end of the array, so that the iterator does not go past `Questions.length`